# Al agregar un producto al carrito se repite y no se actualiza su número correctamente

Tags: javascript

Tengo este simulador de compras de productos, con el inconveniente de que cada vez que sumo un producto al carrito de compras, el mismo se repite y no se actualiza adecuadamente.

Éste es el código:

```js
let cantidadRemeras = 0;
let cantidadCamperas = 0;
let cantidadShorts = 0
let carro = 0;

let comprarRemera = document.getElementById("btnRemera");
comprarRemera.addEventListener("click", sumarRemera)
function sumarRemera() {
    carro += 1800;
    let precio = document.createElement("p");
    cantidadRemeras++;
    if(cantidadRemeras <= 1){
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadRemeras} remera añadida al carro</p>`;
    }else{
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadRemeras} remeras añadidas al carro</p>`;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(precio);
}

let comprarCampera = document.getElementById("btnCampera");
comprarCampera.addEventListener("click", sumarCampera)
function sumarCampera() {
    carro += 2800;
    let precio = document.createElement("p");
    cantidadCamperas++;
    if(cantidadCamperas <= 1){
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadCamperas} campera añadida al carro</p>`;
    }else{
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadCamperas} camperas añadidas al carro</p>`;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(precio);
}

let comprarShort = document.getElementById("btnShort");
comprarShort.addEventListener("click", sumarShort)
function sumarShort() {
    carro += 1200;
    let precio = document.createElement("p");
    cantidadShorts++;
    if(cantidadShorts <= 1){
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadShorts} short añadido al carro</p>`;
    }else{
        precio.innerHTML = `<p>${cantidadShorts} shorts añadidos al carro</p>`;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(precio);
}

let boton = document.getElementById("btnPrincipal");
boton.addEventListener("click", finalizarCompra)
function finalizarCompra() {
    let final = document.createElement("p");
    final.innerHTML = `Valor a abonar: $${carro}`;
    document.body.appendChild(final);

}
```

```html
<button id="btnRemera">+ Remera</button>
<button id="btnCampera">+ Campera</button>
<button id="btnShort">+ Short</button>
<button id="btnPrincipal">Principal</button>
```

Comment: A mí me funciona correctamente tu código. ¿Podrías decirnos cómo reproducir el problema que tienes? ¿Qué secuencia de pulsaciones de agregar elementos al carrito terminan en un fallo? Por cierto, si ya has creado un elemento `<p>`, no agregues un elemento `<p>` hijo adicional en el HTML de los mensajes, y procura usar `innerText` en vez de `innerHTML` para agregar el texto.